# What would the Rosetta stone be defined as?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would something that shows you like the equivalent of something else in another language be defined as? Or a book that teaches you another language be called?

"The "*Rosetta stone*" show that apple is manzana in spanish."

Comment: The ancient language decoder tablet?

Comment: Does it have to be a single word? *Bilingual* or *foreign language **dictionary*** (or @Cameron's ***lexicon*** with appropriate adjective) is the most common term for something used to look up "apple" in English and get "manzana" in Spanish (or vice versa). For something that teaches another language, you'd use *[foreign] language **textbook*** or maybe ***primer*** or ***grammar***. And your own ***Rosetta Stone*** can be used for something that is used to decode something that was previously unknown (even—or especially—if that wasn't its original purpose).

Comment: Secret decoder ring, er, tablet.

Comment: Typically you refer to the as *language1 - language2 dictionaries*  E.g. My Spanish-English Dictionary says that apple is manzana in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a [**translator**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/translator)

> - A person who translates from one language into another, especially as a profession
> - A computer program that translates from one programming language into another

The general process would be called [**translation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/translation)

> - The process of translating words or text from one language into another.

A physical book might be known as a *translation guide*.

Answer (score 0):

[***Lexicon***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lexicon) is probably the best word for what you are looking for:

> 2. the vocabulary of a particular language, field, social class, person, etc.

Comment: A lexicon is usually monolingual.

Comment: True, but the only other term I can think of would be a *translation guide*, which is not a single word, although it is the generally accepted term from what I can see online.

Answer (score -1):

The Rosetta Stone is a **language course**. The course is not a lexicon, dictionary, or translator. It teaches students a new language online, at their own pace.

[Rosetta Stone site ...](http://www.rosettastone.com)

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Rosetta_Stone.JPG